# Angular 2 Email Validator

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having trouble with my simple email validator. My .ts page that controls my html has this code:

```
import {EmailValidator} from  '../../validators/email';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/auth-signup/auth-signup.html',
})

export class AuthSignupPage {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
     this.slideOneForm = new FormGroup({
          firstName: new FormControl('', [
              Validators.maxLength(30), 
              Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'),
              Validators.required
              ]),
          lastName: new FormControl('', [
              Validators.maxLength(30), 
              Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), 
              Validators.required]),
          email: new FormControl('', [
              Validators.maxLength(30), 
              EmailValidator.isValidMailFormat, 
              Validators.required]),
          password: new FormControl('', [
              Validators.maxLength(30), 
              Validators.required]),
          confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [
              Validators.maxLength(30), 
              Validators.required])
      });
  }
}
```

My HTML code is:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Email (this will be your login/username)</ion-label>
    <ion-input #email (change)="elementChanged(email)" formControlName="email" type="email" [class.invalid]="!slideOneForm.controls.email.valid && (emailChanged || submitAttempt)"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

And finally, my email.ts that holds my validator looks like this:

```
import {Control} from '@angular/common';


export class EmailValidator {

   static isValidMailFormat(control: Control){
        var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;

        if (control.value != "" && (control.value.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value))) {
            return { "Please provide a valid email": true };
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I keep having errors when referencing this validator in my main .ts file. For example, I get this error when hovering over "EmailValidator.isValidMailFormat"

```
[ts] 
Argument of type '(ValidatorFn | ((control: Control) => { "Please provide a valid email": boolean; }))[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]'.
  Type '(ValidatorFn | ((control: Control) => { "Please provide a valid email": boolean; }))[]' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn[]'.
    Type 'ValidatorFn | ((control: Control) => { "Please provide a valid email": boolean; })' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
      Type '(control: Control) => { "Please provide a valid email": boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
        Types of parameters 'control' and 'c' are incompatible.
          Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'Control'.
            Property 'updateValue' is missing in type 'AbstractControl'.
import EmailValidator
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23):

Even better, now, Angular 4 has email validator built-in
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-6
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13709

Just add **email** to the  tag. For example,

```
  <form #f="ngForm">
    <input type="email" ngModel name="email" required email>
    <button [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
    <p>Form State: {{f.valid?'VALID':'INVALID'}}</p>
  </form>
```

Comment: but still need a little more validation because i can write test@test 
withou '.com' which is not a valid email

Comment: user@host IS a valid email.   The host part is not required to have a TLD to be valid.  Of course, your mail router will only attempt to route on your local domain.

Comment: Unfortunately this E-Mail Validator validates john.doe@gmail to true even though it is missing the .com part.

Comment: These comments are good examples of why people shouldn't be writing their own email validators--they end up writing validators for what they "think" is valid...

Comment: `john.doe@gmail` is a valid email address.

Answer (score 12):

This was solved by changing the imported class from `Control` to `FormControl` in the first line of my validator.ts:

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';


export class EmailValidator {

   static isValidMailFormat(control: FormControl){
        let EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;

        if (control.value != "" && (control.value.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value))) {
            return { "Please provide a valid email": true };
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest to change `control.value != ""` to `control.value`, as it may produce uncaught exceptions in some cases.

Answer (score 6):

**Angular 9+ and Ionic 5+**

Default Angular Email validator is not enough for my use case. So I have used this:

*form.ts*

```
     this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
         
          email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
                      Validators.pattern(RegularExpressionConstant.EMAIL)])],
          });
```

*regular-expression.constant.ts*

```
export class RegularExpressionConstant {
    static EMAIL: RegExp = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
}
```

Comment: That's work for me thanks. code below: `email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.email])]`

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="email" pattern="^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$">
```

The pattern attribute can be used for custom validation

Comment: quite simple really. The pattern attribute let you write your own regex pattern for validation fx

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `Validators.pattern('^[^\\s@]+@[^\\s@]+\\.[^\\s@]{2,}$')`

**.ts code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { UserDetails } from '../../app/Model/UserDetails';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'  
})
export class LoginPage {
logForm: FormGroup;
  email: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.logForm = formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[^\\s@]+@[^\\s@]+\\.[^\\s@]{2,}$'), Validators.minLength(1)])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])],

    });
  }


  onSubmit(value: any): void {
    if (this.logForm.valid) {
      //window.localStorage.setItem('username', value.username);
      //window.localStorage.setItem('password', value.password);    
    }
  }


}
```

**HTML code:**

```
    <form [formGroup]="logForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(logForm.value)">
      <div class="login-user-input">

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="label"  fixed>Email</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="user.Email" ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngIf="logForm.controls.email.hasError('pattern') && logForm.controls.email.touched">
          <p>Please enter valid Email</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="label"  fixed>Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password" maxlength="8" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngIf="logForm.controls.password.hasError('minLength') && logForm.controls.password.touched">
          <p>Please enter valid Password</p>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button text-center class="customersubmitbtn" [disabled]="!logForm.valid" color="primary" >Login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // SIMPLE SNIPPIT CODE
    
        this.myReactiveForm = new FormGroup({
              id: new FormControl(''),
              fullName: new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2),Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$')])),
              email: new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.pattern(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)])),
              mobile: new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern("^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$")])),
              address: new FormControl(''),
```