# How to add custom validation after control initialization in angular 4 reactive form?

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I am working on angular 4 application and using reactive forms.

In one of my forms I need to add custom validation to control after its initialization on checkbox check and remove it on checkbox uncheck.

CODE

form.component.ts

```
   form : FormGroup;
    constructor( private formGroup : FormBuilder){}
    ngOnInit() {
       this.form = this.formGroup.group({ 
          name : ["", [Validators.required, this.textValidation]]
       });
    }

    public textValidation(control:FormControl)  
    {    
      if(control.value && (control.value).replace(/\s/g, "").length < 1)    
      {      
         return {'stringCheck': true};    
      }    
      return '';  
    }

    addValidation(isChecked)
    {
       if(isChecked){  this.form.controls['name'].setValidators([Validators.required,this.textValidation]);
       }else{
         this.form.controls['name'].clearValidators();
       } 
        this.form.controls['name'].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
```

form.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
   <input type="checkbox" (change)="addValidation($event.target.checked)">
   <div>
      <label>Name</label>
      <imput type="text formControlName="name">
      <small *ngIf="(form.controls['name'].hasError('required') || form.controls['name'].hasError('stringCheck')>Error</small>
   </div>

</form>
```

Getting this error.

> /home/iron/Desktop/BK-admin/bookingkoala_admin/src/app/Industries/AddFrequency/AddFrequency.component.ts
>   (242,79): Argument of type '(((control: AbstractControl) =>
>   ValidationErrors) | ((control: FormControl) => "" | { 'stringChec...'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]'. 
>   Type '(((control: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors) | ((control:
>   FormControl) => "" | { 'stringChec...' is not assignable to type
>   'ValidatorFn[]'.
>       Type '((control: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors) | ((control: FormControl) => "" | { 'stringCheck...' is not assignable
>   to type 'ValidatorFn'.
>         Type '(control: FormControl) => "" | { 'stringCheck': boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
>           Type '"" | { 'stringCheck': boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'.
>             Type '""' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'.

If any one know how to fix it please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically telling you the problem directly:

```
  addValidation(isChecked)
    {
       if(isChecked){  this.form.controls['name'].setValidators([Validators.required,this.textValidation]);
       }else{
         this.form.controls['name'].clearValidators();
       } 
        this.form.controls['name'].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
```

your string from the method:

```
 public textValidation(control:FormControl)  
    {    
      if(control.value && (control.value).replace(/\s/g, "").length < 1)    
      {      
         return {'stringCheck': true};    
      }    
      return '';  
    }
```

Cannot be assigned to validationError type.

meaning this line is invalid:

```
 if(isChecked){  this.form.controls['name'].setValidators([Validators.required,this.textValidation]);
```

Take a look at this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238262/angular-2-email-validator) to get a little sense about what is happening and how to work with validation errors.